# Subject Name not showing in my email using mail command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, solaris, sunos

I am using mail command to send an email. It works fine.

```
echo "Ignore this email" | mail -s "Test Data" DL-host-PD-WAS-TT_Emp@corp.host.com
```

But the only confusion I have is, in my email I didn't get any subject and it always show as `(no subject)` in my email as I am also specifying  subject option in the above command as `-s` but it is not working I guess somehow.

I am running SunOS.

```
bash-3.00$ uname -a
SunOS lvsaishdc3in0001 5.10 Generic_142901-02 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

And also I am not seeing `To:` list in my email. How can I make this thing works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On all Solaris systems, you should not use `"mail"`, you should use `"mailx"`.
Try using `mailx`. http://www.cisl.ucar.edu/tcg/consweb/Solaris/mail.html

Modify your command like this-

```
echo "Ignore this email" | mailx -s "Test Data" DL-host-PD-WAS-TT_Emp@corp.host.com
```

Comment: Same issue as with the OP. Got resolved switching to mailx, however, mail itself did work on some Solaris systems (with the Subj), and did not on others.